# Connections between Domain, Nginx and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, dns, ip

I want to understand the connections between Nginx Config Files, Domains and Wordpress Site URL.

I map my domain blog.example.com to my ip: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/wordpress/
in the Wordpress SiteUrl i set blog.example.com

How should my NGINX configuration file look like?

### Edit

My Configuration works in the first step, I get to the Frontpage, but when clicking on permalinks, I get redirected to the Frontpage again instead of the Post.

My current Config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/wordpress/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php
    server_name blog.example.com;

    location ~\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri?$args;
     }

     location / {
         try_files $uri /index.php$args;
     }
}
```

### Edit

In Nginx Debug Log I see the REQUEST_URI is /wordpress/postname/
but as i understand it should be just /postname/

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    return 404; # default
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blog.example.com;

    location / {
        return 301 http://blog.example.com/wordpress;
    }
    location ^~ /wordpress {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the first part working with another approach and updated my question. Thanks for your answer!